# call function on page mouse out javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can you call a function when the the cursor leaves the whole page? I already tried `onmouseout` for the `html` tag but the content was positioned above it. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can try the opposite ? onmouseon ?

Comment: This looks like it should do the trick: http://bradsknutson.com/blog/javascript-detect-mouse-leaving-browser-window/

Comment: do browsers support it well? Never heard of it. Tried googling it...